# Сайт на сервере Uvicorn FastApi не работает при вводе адреса без https. Как сделать, чтобы работал?

Tags: python, .htaccess, https, fastapi, uvicorn

Сервер написан на Python FastApi, запускается через Uvicorn на Windows 10.

После получения и установки ssl сертииката для безопасного https соединения перестало заходить на сайт по домену без приписки https. Нагуглил, что требуется файл  .htaccess с прописанной переадресацией при обычном http запросе на страницу с https, но либо не правильно прописал настройки, либо сервер не видит этого файла, т.к. проблему решить не удалось.

Объясните пожалуйста какие настройки нужно прописать в .htaccess и как его подключить к серверу.

Также при входе через  https перестал работать websocket.

Конфигурация веб сервера:

```
uvicorn.run("server:app", host="192.168.0.102", port=443, log_level="info", reload=True, ssl_keyfile="./privkey3.pem", ssl_certfile="./fullchain3.pem")
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, добавил.

Comment: ассоциация https://stackoverflow.com/q/69138537/10562663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример и перевод с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69426728/10562663)

Запустите `subprocess`, который возвращает ответ о перенаправлении с одного порта на другой.

В `main.py`

```py
from subprocess import Popen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Popen(['python', '-m', 'https_redirect'])
    uvicorn.run(
        'server:app', port=443, host='192.168.0.102',
        reload=True,
        ssl_keyfile='./privkey3.pem',
        ssl_certfile='./fullchain3.pem')
```

В `https_redirect.py`

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse

app = FastAPI()


@app.route('/{_:path}')
async def https_redirect(request: Request):
    return RedirectResponse(request.url.replace(scheme='https'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('https_redirect:app', port=80, host='192.168.0.102')
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло! Осталось только решить проблему с Websocket. После подключения сертификатов он перестал работать. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The operation is insecure. Ругает JS код, там вписан внешний айпи домена без портов.

Comment: Нашёл решение с Websocket нужно в JS вместо new WebSocket(`ws:// написать new WebSocket(`wss://